# Pandas подсчитать количество одинаковых записей в столбце

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Имеется DataFrame

```
   First name Last name Study Status  Day  Month  Year    DayWeek
   0        Ivan    Ivanov   ihc   done    1      8  2020   Saturday
   1        Ivan    Ivanov  hist  doing    8      8  2020   Saturday
   2        Ivan    Ivanov   ihc  to_do    3      8  2020     Monday
   3        Ivan    Ivanov   ihc   done    4      8  2020    Tuesday
   4        Ivan    Ivanov  hist  doing    5      8  2020  Wednesday
   5        Ivan    Ivanov   ihc  to_do    6      8  2020   Thursday
   6        Ivan    Ivanov   ihc   done    7      8  2020     Friday
   7        Ivan    Ivanov  hist  doing    8      8  2020   Saturday
   8        Ivan    Ivanov   ihc  to_do    9      8  2020     Sunday
   9        Ivan    Ivanov   ihc   done   10      8  2020     Monday
   10       Ivan    Ivanov  hist  doing   11      8  2020    Tuesday
   11       Ivan    Ivanov   ihc   done   12      8  2020  Wednesday
   12       Ivan    Ivanov  hist  doing   13      8  2020   Thursday
   13       Ivan    Ivanov   ihc  to_do   14      8  2020     Friday
   14       Ivan    Ivanov   ihc   done   15      8  2020   Saturday
   15       Ivan    Ivanov  hist  doing   16      8  2020     Sunday
   16       Ivan    Ivanov   ihc  to_do   17      8  2020     Monday
   17       Ivan    Ivanov   ihc   done   18      8  2020    Tuesday
   18       Ivan    Ivanov  hist  doing   19      8  2020  Wednesday
   19       Ivan    Ivanov   ihc  to_do   20      8  2020   Thursday
   20       Ivan    Ivanov   ihc   done   21      8  2020     Friday
   21       Ivan    Ivanov  hist  doing   22      8  2020   Saturday
   22       Ivan    Ivanov   ihc   done    5      8  2020  Wednesday
   23       Ivan    Ivanov  hist  doing    5      8  2020  Wednesday
   24       Ivan    Ivanov   ihc  to_do    3      8  2020     Monday
   25       Ivan    Ivanov   ihc   done    5      8  2020  Wednesday
```

Здесь показаны какие мед.исследования (Study) были сделаны пациенту и какого числа (Day,Month).
Как видно, несколько исследований были сделаны в один день (5 августа были сделаны 4 исследования).
Исходя из этого, мне нужно сделать новый датафрейм, где:

```
колонка1-число месяца  колонка2-количество исследований в день
```

Пример:

```
Day    Amount
1       1
2       0
3       2
4       1
5       4
```

и.тд.

Как это сделать, подскажите,плз

Comment: Попробуй воспользоваться функцией groupBy - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ещё можно использовать функцию `value_counts`, если требуется посчитать число иссделований в рамках месяца:

```
    df = df['Day'].value_counts().rename_axis('Day').reset_index(name='Amount')
```

А в общем случае с `groupBy` будет что-то подобное:

```
    df = DataFrame({'count' : df1.groupby( ["Day", "Month", "Year"] ).size()}).reset_index()
```